# how to get the image from expressjs and display the image into react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, vite

I create a registration form that can get the data from the users and also their profile picture and i store the image into my public folder in my server. the path structure is **server/public/avatar** but the problem is the express.static is not working to me it gaves me the error that **Connot Get**
i tried this syntax
app.use(express.static('public'));  = not working
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); = not working
app.use('/avatar',express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public/avatar'))); = not working
app.use('/avatar',express.static(path.join(_*dirname + '../public/avatar'))); = not working
this is my api
http://localhost:3001/avatar/avatar_url*.jpg
please help me with my problem i am really new with nodejs and react

I would like to get the profile picture of the user and display their profile into my react using mapping function this is my code into my react to get the profile picture <img className="w-10 h-10 rounded-full" src={`http://localhost:3001/avatar/${value?.avatar_url}`}/> {value.first_name} {value.last_name}

Comment: I see you have already found the solution. However, please [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your code. It helps others

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem i just add this code **app.use(express.static('public'));** into my index.js file